# regex pattern losses last character

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following regex to extract a domain from a url:  `"^(http:\\/\\/|https:\\/\\/)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+).[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-z]{3}.?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$"` when I get the 3rd group, I get a the domain missing the last charcter in it. for example: facebook becomes faceboo

I'm using Java 8

The regex Works fine in case of having a path (Group 4) that doesn't have any numbers in it.
if I put a number into the 4th group it cuts the domain's last character.

Comment: You could have set the "s" of https optional instead of having both http and https. And your URL only have `.` ? no `/`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the dot characters

```
"^(http:\\/\\/|https:\\/\\/)?(www\\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\\.[a-z]{3}\\.?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$"
```

It's a special character in regex that means "Any character", which will mean it matches a dot, or any letter.

Comment: The regex Works fine in case of having a path (Group 4) that doesn't have any numbers in it. if I put a number into the 4th group it cuts the domain's last character.